# How to fill NA by surrounding mean by group in R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I don't really know how to fill NAs by calculating the average of its surroundings by group. In other words, I don't want data in other groups to be calculated in the surrounding average.

I have a *stock* dataset like that:

```
Key | Company_Name | Price    |
--  | --------     | -------- |
1   | A            | 12       |
2   | A            | 13       |
3   | A            | 12       |
4   | A            | NA       |
5   | A            | NA       |
6   | B            | 20       |
7   | B            | 21       |
8   | B            | NA       |
```

I want to impute those NAs by calculating the average of its 4 surroundings. However, the challenge is that I don't know how to do this **by group**. For example, for the 5th observation, I don't want it to be affected by B's price.

My expected output is:

```
Key | Company_Name | Price    |
--  | --------     | -------- |
1   | A            | 12       |
2   | A            | 13       |
3   | A            | 12       |
4   | A            | 12.33    |
5   | A            | 12.33    |
6   | B            | 20       |
7   | B            | 21       |
8   | B            | 20.5     |
```

Some links that I tried to learn from:

1. https://www.statology.org/r-moving-average-by-group/
2. https://statisticsglobe.com/replace-na-mean-by-group-r

What I have tried:

- Without grouping, I used `na_ma()` from `ImputeTS` library as the following, and it works:

```
stock$Price = na_ma(stock$Price, k=2, weighting = 'simple')
```

- But when I want to include `group_by()` into consideration to improve accuracy of my imputation, it caused an error:

```
stock2 = stock %>% 
      group_by(Company_Name) %>%
      mutate(Price = na_ma(stock$Price, k=2, weighting = 'simple'))
```

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Price = na_ma(stock$Price, k=2, weighting = 'simple')`.
ℹ In group 1: `Name = "A."`.
Caused by error:
! `Stock` must be size 76 or 1, not 120471.
Backtrace:

1. bm_no_na %>% group_by(Company_Name) %>% ...
2. dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)

Comment: A few advices: 1 - never use the dolar sign operator inside dplyr. It is redundant and can get you in trouble in several ways. You can replace `a_ma(stock$Price ....` with `a_ma(Price ...`. This alone may solve your problem.

Comment: 2 - always consider including code for your data instead of just the formated tables. You can use `dput(stock)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace missing values with the simple `mean()` function :

```
fill_na <- function(x) ifelse( is.na(x),mean(x, na.rm=T), x)

   stock2 <- stock %>% 
          group_by(Company_Name) %>% 
          mutate_at(vars("Price") , fill_na) 

stock2
   Key Company_Name Price
  <int> <chr>        <dbl>
1     1 A             12  
2     2 A             13  
3     3 A             12  
4     4 A             12.3
5     5 A             12.3
6     6 B             20  
7     7 B             21  
8     8 B             20.5
```

or using `ImputeTS` (Note that the issue with your code, as mentioned by GuedesBF, is to avoid using `$` inside `dplyr`):

```
library(ImputeTS)
stock2 <- stock %>% 
  group_by(Company_Name) %>% 
  mutate(Price = na_ma(Price, k=2, weighting = 'simple'))

stock2

   Key Company_Name Price
  <int> <chr>        <dbl>
1     1 A             12  
2     2 A             13  
3     3 A             12  
4     4 A             12.5
5     5 A             12.5
6     6 B             20  
7     7 B             21  
8     8 B             20.5
```

## Example data

```
stock <- read.table(text = "Key Company_Name    Price
1   A   12
2   A   13
3   A   12
4   A   NA
5   A   NA
6   B   20
7   B   21
8   B   NA
",header=T)
```